# pip not installing requirements for a project on test PyPi

Tags: python, pip, qiskit

- I have recently uploaded a python package to Test PyPI following [this](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial.
- When I try to use the command `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ qiskit-trebugger` for installing my project, only the project is installed, not its dependencies.
- I have used a static `setup.cfg` file and correctly listed requirements in the `pyproject.toml` before generating and uploading the `dist`.
- Is there anything specific that needs to be done for the build to contain the dependencies of the project, which need to be installed?
- The code is available [here](https://github.com/TheGupta2012/qiskit-timeline-debugger)

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+test.pypi.org

Comment: You dependencies are not at test.pypi.org so you have to install them from main pypi.org: `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index https://pypi.org/simple/ qiskit-trebugger`

Comment: That's only half the issue here actually. It's not actually getting to that point because of issues in the package metadata it doesn't actually list any dependencies. I was typing an answer while this question was closed if it's reopened I can elaborate on the details there (it's longer than the comment character limit).